# Parsing of NSDictionary of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services, restkit

I am using Restkit API to parse a JSON Reply, which I have received from my webserver. The reply from the webserver is in this form.scre[image]

JSON reply is this

```
{"Menu Items":[
            {
                "ID":393,
                "Title":"Lentil Soup",
                "Description":"This is extremely tasty",
                "Image":"Lentil_1.png"
            },
            {   
                "ID":392,
                "Title":"Chicken Tortilla Soup",
                "Description":"Quick. Simple. Delicious.":"$20",
                "Image":"Tortilla_3.png"
            }
        ]
```

}

I am using the below code to get the response, but fails to get any response.

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL.com"];

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL]; // init by url
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];

//set up restkit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
//setup object mapping
//addAttributeMappingsFromArray is a shortcut method to use when the JSON and your data model share the same keys, which is “name” in your case.

RKObjectMapping* boyMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ListItem class] ];
[boyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"ID"]];

// register mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:boyMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                        pathPattern:@"/demo/restaurant/app/menu_lists.php"
                                            keyPath:@"Menu Items"
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    NSDictionary *parameterDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_slugString, @"item_slug", nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/demo/restaurant/app/menu_lists.php"
                                       parameters:parameterDict
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              _menuItems = mappingResult.array;
                                              NSLog(@"menuItems is %@", _menuItems);
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"What do you mean by 'there is no coffee?': %@", error);
                                          }];
```

every time it go to the failure Block.

Comment: What is the error in the debug log?

Comment: this is the error log , which i get "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."

Comment: Paste the actual JSON that was received. Turn on trace logging.

Comment: @Wain i have pasted the JSON Reply

Comment: Can't see issues in what you've shown, so you'll need to include more of the log output

Comment: @Wain, this is the error log "failed to match all (0) response descriptors:, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null"

Answer (score 1):

(assuming the response received has a status code of 200)

You create an object manager:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
```

then you configure it. But, then you try to use it with:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:...
```

and this is using a different instance that has been created somewhere else in the code and doesn't have any of the configuration you set on `objectManager`.

You need to reorganise your code to ensure you create and appropriately use your object manager(s).